# Is $\mathbb{N}$ infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively the answer is yes. According to the definition, a set $A$ is infinite if there is no bijection between $A$ and some natural number.

Now, I don't know the problem of my reasoning. Accordingly the funcion $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow 0$ is a bijection (Because $f\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times 0=\emptyset$ and then it's vacuously true that $\forall a\in \mathbb{N}\forall b\in \emptyset((a,b)\in f \wedge(a,c)\in f\Longrightarrow b=c)$.

Also, if I wanted to prove that indeed $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, the only option I see is by making a proof by induction. In such a case then my statement should be false. I don't know...

**Edit**: The approach to prove that there is a biyection is the same way as to proove that it's a function:

It's injective: It's vacously true that $\forall a\in \mathbb{N}\forall b\in \emptyset((a,b)\in f \wedge(c,b)\in f\Longrightarrow a=c)$.

It's surjective: It's vacuously true that $\forall a\in \emptyset \exists b((a,b)\in f)$.

Now I know my problems are in my understanding of the meaning of "vacously". It would be very nice if you guys could tell me the mistakes in it and also in my definitions.

Comment: A set A is infinite if there is no bijection between A and $\mathbb{N}$ (not some natural number).

Comment: @LordSoth: No. Daniela's characterization is correct (unless you ask Dedekind's ghost, and even then, you're incorrect).

Comment: You have explained why $n\mapsto 0$ is a *function*, but not why it is a *bijection*. And it isn't one.

Comment: If by $0$ you mean $\phi$, then $f$ is not a function. You must assign to each natural number an element of the codomain, which is impossible here.

Comment: If you reject [the axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity), which [some people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism) do, then $\mathbb{N}$ is not a set, and hence vacuously not infinite.

Comment: I must say I'm amused at how much disagreement has gone on in the comments so far: (1) You're wrong about your definition. (2) No, she's right and you're wrong. (3) You're partially right in this respect. (4) No, in that respect she's wrong.

Comment: Even if you reject the axiom of infinity, the (possibly proper) class of natural numbers is not in a one-to-one correspondence with any natural number.

Comment: @David, if by $\phi$ you mean $\varnothing$, then that is true but doesn't get to the heart of the problem.

Comment: @dfeuer: True, a proper class can't be in bijection with a natural number (a set), but since proper classes don't formally exist (in ZF), that's not a particularly enlightening/useful statement. P.S.: It turns out that the natural numbers are a set if and only if the Axiom of Infinity holds.

Comment: @CameronBuie They don't formally exist in ZF, but they exist just fine in NBG and Morse-Kelley set theory.

Comment: @dfeuer: Fair point.

Comment: @dfeuer I made an edit to write the way I proved that $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Daniela, my claim that your proof that it is a function was correct was itself incorrect, as I misread your statement. There is no such function, because you missed the part of the definition of a function requiring that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N) (\exists x \in 0) (x,y)\in f$, which does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no total function $f:\Bbb N\to 0$: $0$ is the empty set, so $\Bbb N\times 0=\varnothing$, and therefore the domain of $f$ is empty. Some would not call this a function on $\Bbb N$ at all; others would call it a *partial function* on $\Bbb N$.

But all of this is beside the point: in order to show that $\Bbb N$ was finite, you would have to find a **bijection** between $\Bbb N$ and some $n\in\Bbb N$. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ it is certainly possible to find a surjection $f:\Bbb N\to n$ (where $n=\{0,\dots,n-1\}$): one possibility is

$$f(k)=\begin{cases}
k,&\text{if }k\in n\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

This function is certainly not a bijection, however, since $f(0)=f(n)=f(n+1)=\ldots=0$. And it turns out to be impossible to find such a bijection, so $\Bbb N$ must be infinite.

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!. After reading your explanation a lot of times now I see my problem. Everything is fine, except in my interpretation to the definition $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow 0  $, which means $Dom(f)=\mathbb{N}$ and $Ran(f)= \emptyset$.

Comment: @Daniela: You’re welcome! One small correction: $f:X\to Y$ is normally understood to mean that $\operatorname{Dom}(f)=X$ and $\operatorname{Ran}(f)\subseteq Y$: the domain is all of $X$, but the range doesn’t have to be all of $Y$.

Comment: my God! thanks again. Saludos from Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to prove that every finite, totally ordered set has a greatest element.